# What is the easiest way to make a RaspberryPi forward data to a database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, raspberry-pi

I have a smartplug (Tp link HS110) installed in my local network. Now I want that the power usage that this smartplug uses is "captured" by my Raspberry (also in my local network), and the raspberry should send this data to a influxDB or DynamoDB hosted on an aws server.

How can I achieve this in an efficient way, having as less programs/ stuff running on the raspberry as possible? Which OS could fit here?
Maybe someone has done something similar and can help me out?

I would prefer a solution with node.js, since I want to work with the data out of the DB later on in an aws Lambda function (which will probably be written in node.js) and process it further.

Thanks!

Comment: Where, _exactly_, are you having problems? Do you know how to retrieve information from the smart plug? Are you able to do that with Node? Have you used the AWS SDK for Node? Are you familiar with using DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

**Option 1:** Send the data via MQTT to AWS Internet of Things (IoT) that can then store the data in DynamoDB:

[image: AWS IoT]

**Option 2:** Put an AWS SDK on the device and communicate with DynamoDB directly.

See:

- [Using the AWS IoT device SDKs on a Raspberry Pi - AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sdk-tutorials.html)
- [Setting up your Raspberry Pi and moisture sensor - AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-moisture-raspi-setup.html)
- [Use a Raspberry Pi to communicate with Amazon AWS IoT](https://www.balena.io/blog/use-a-raspberry-pi-to-communicate-with-amazon-aws-iot/)